# Light bulb dimensions

Tags: lighting, bulb

I need to change some light bulbs and the process has become tremendous because I cannot find detailed size and type charts to compare against what I already have.

Where could I find such a chart that would give me the bulb type (i.e. R14), the base type (i.e. E26), and their dimensions (preferably in `mm`).

### EDIT

I'm interested in US type bulbs.

Comment: Stating your location will help immensely in getting you the proper replies.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey in USA. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I'd just take the old bulbs with me to a store for comparison.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I'd gladly do that if the actual stores would have them. But these bulbs I only found them online.

Comment: Try emailing a few online retailers giving the dimensions of your current bulb? If any answer - at least you know their customer service is good.